# JQuery SlideToggle problem in IE7 with button that has a bg-image

Tags: jquery-ui, button, internet-explorer-7, background-image

In using Jquery's SlideToggle, I'm finding a problem with the handling of background images for a button element in IE7.

When the div is toggled, the background image takes a few more milliseconds before disappearing.  The overall effect is not very clean.  And it works fine in Chrome or Firefox.

Has anyone seen this before or any ideas how to solve this?

You can see an example of it here:
http://www.casa-luciano.com/test/lists.asp

Thanks in advance for anyone's help, and let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late - but try adding position:relative to the div parent; works for me.